# Remove multiple keys from Map in efficient way?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map<String,String>` with large number of key values pairs. Now I want to remove selected keys from that `Map`. Following code shows what I did to achieve that.

```
Set keySet = new HashSet(); //I added keys to keySet which I want to remove.
```

Then :

```
Iterator entriesIterator = keySet.iterator();
while (entriesIterator.hasNext()) {
   map.remove( entriesIterator.next().toString());
}
```

This is working fine. What would be the better approach?

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Assuming your set contains the strings you want to remove, you can use [the `keySet` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) and `map.keySet().removeAll(keySet);`.

> `keySet` returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Contrived example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "");
map.put("b", "");
map.put("c", "");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<> ();
set.add("a");
set.add("b");

map.keySet().removeAll(set);

System.out.println(map); //only contains "c"
```

Comment: your suggestion is great. I guess removeAll(keySet) is doing what I did there

Comment: in terms of "efficiency" its probably just a for loop underneath, but in terms of cleaner code, nice win :)

Comment: Obvious once you see it - thanks! Still baffles me why Map does have removeAll, and for that matter isnt Iterable over the entrySet directly

Comment: Not working for me on Jenkins jvm

Answer (score 32):

For the sake of completion, and since Google brings you here when you look for a way to achieve this:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> /* decide what you want to remove here */ );
```

This does not assume you have a predefined set of keys to remove but rather assumes you have a condition on which the keys should be removed. From the question, it is unclear if these keys are added manually or based on some sort of condition. In the latter case, this might be the cleaner code.

For the former case, this (untested) code might work as well:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> keySet.contains(entry.getKey()) );
```

But obviously [the answer provided by @assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17675899/3653975) is much cleaner in this case!

Answer (score 12):

Just for the sake of completeness:

As guessed `java.util.AbstractSet#removeAll` really iterates over all entries, but with one little trick: It uses the iterator of the smaller collection:

```java
if (size() <= collection.size()) {
    Iterator<?> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (collection.contains(it.next())) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
} else {
    Iterator<?> it = collection.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        remove(it.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Java stream:

```
keySet.forEach(map::remove);
```

Comment: This will not solve the actual request of removing multiple selected keys, as it doesn't have select parameter.

Comment: @dildeepak, what do you mean with "select parameter"?