# Remove elements from TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I have built a word counter in Java using `Map<String, Integer>` where a word is the `String` and the amount of times that word was said in a .txt document is `Integer`. This all works great. Right now I am trying to get a part where I have `String[] noWords = [list of words to exclude]` such as prepositions and extremely common words --> "the, and, a, etc".

I can't get a loop going where the words will look through the list and delete is it equals the element of the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full running code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class WordCounter {

    public static void run(String filename, String filename2) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String[] noWords = {"aboard", "about", "above", "across", "after", "against", "along", "amid", "among", "anti", "around", "as", "at", "before", "behind", "below", "beneath", "beside", "besides", "between", "beyond", "but", "by", "concerning", "considering", "despite", "down", "during", "except", "excepting", "excluding", "following", "for", "from", "in", "inside", "into", "like", "minus", "near", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "opposite", "outside", "over", "past", "per", "plus", "regarding", "round", "save", "since", "than", "through", "to", "toward", "towards", "under", "underneath", "unlike", "until", "up", "upon", "versus", "via", "with", "within", "without", "all", "another", "any", "anybody", "anyone", "anything", "both", "each", "either", "everybody", "everyone", "everything", "few", "he", "her", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "I", "it", "its", "itself", "many", "me mine", "more", "most", "much", "my", "myself", "neither", "no one", "nobody", "none", "nothing", "one", "other", "others", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "several", "she", "some", "somebody", "someone", "something", "that", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "these", "they", "this", "those", "us", "we", "what", "whatever", "which", "whichever", "who", "whoever", "whom", "whomever", "whose", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"};

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = readFile(filename2);

        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : wordCount.values()) {
            sum += i;
        }
        int amount = wordCount.size();

        Set<String> keySet = wordCount.keySet();
        for (String key : keySet) {
            int value = wordCount.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + " was said " + value + " time(s) in "+filename);
        }

        System.out.println("\ntotal amount of words:  " + sum);
        System.out.println("total amount of different words: " + amount + "\n");

        wordCount.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(noWords));

        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = wordCount.entrySet();
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        int topResults = 5;
        int counter = 1;

        Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext() && topResults > 0 ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
            System.out.println(counter + ".  \"" + entry.getKey() + "\" was said " + entry.getValue() + " times");
            topResults --;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        int counter;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        in.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String next = in.next().toLowerCase();
            if (wordCount.get(next) == null) {
                counter = 1;
                wordCount.put(next, counter);
            } else {
                counter = wordCount.get(next) + 1;
                wordCount.put(next, counter);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

It is being called in a separate file in the main via:

```
WordCounter counter = new WordCounter();
System.out.print("directions:\n" +
                "place your text file in the \"textfiles\" folder\n\n" +
                "file name:  ");
String counterInputFile = s.nextLine();
String counterInputFile2 = "textfiles/"+counterInputFile;
try {
    counter.run(counterInputFile, counterInputFile2);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found");
}
```

Comment: You just need to call `wordcount.keySet().removeAll()` check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675804/remove-multiple-keys-from-map-in-efficient-way

Comment: where would I implement that?

Comment: When you want to remove words from your map. `wordCount.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(noWords));`

Comment: @JBNizet i placed the line above where I declare the Set on line 42 and it didn't seem to work - did I place it in the wrong area?

Comment: Define "didn't seem to work" precisely. Also remember that we don't have line numbers here.

Comment: It did not remove the words listed from the array inside the map. I altered the code to show what I added and changed

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it works as expected.

Comment: OML i just realized why I didn't think it wasn't working...thank you for the help and sorry if you were frustrated