# Remove list items from HashMap efficiently

Tags: java, spring

I have a HashMap where the key is an Id and the value is and object. I have a separate list of Contacts. If the contacts list has an id that matches a key value in the HashMap, I want to remove the item from the HashMap. Whats the most efficent way to do this?

I tried the follwing but it didn't do anything:

```
List<C> contacts;

    Map<Integer, SurveyAnswer<?>> qaMapInit = qaList.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(SurveyAnswer::getSurveyAnswerPk, (qa) -> qa)
            );

qaMapInit.keySet().removeAll(contacts);
```

I'm using Java 8

Comment: Note that a `HashMap`, for keys, has a lookup time complexity of *O(1)*, which is fairly efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
qaMapInit.keySet().removeAll(contacts);
```

isn't quite right.

The best you can do is

```
for (C contact: contacts) {
   qaMapInit.remove(contact.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** Do not make actual use of my Answer here. In real work, I would go with the simple solution shown in correct [Answer by Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716951/642706).

---

Given that you were attempting to use streams, I did the same. Below are my results. Note: Usually streams can simplify long or convoluted conventional code. But this here is an example of the opposite. My stream-based code is less clear than Wasserman’s.

First, we establish an example class similar to yours. I use a Java 16+ [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for brevity, but that is besides the point here.

```
record Person( Integer id , String name ) { }
```

For example data, I make an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) of people having ID values of 1, 2, and 3.

```java
List < Person > people = List.of(
        new Person( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
        new Person( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
        new Person( 3 , "Carol" )
);
```

And an example map of person’s ID to their survey answer.

```java
Map < Integer, String > mapOfPersonIdToAnswer =
        new HashMap <>(
                Map.of(
                        1 , "Poodle" ,
                        3 , "Cockatiel" ,
                        4 , "Akita"
                ) );
```

Now comes our logic.

The main problem in the Question’s code is that you were asking the `removeAll` method to compare the `C` objects in your list of contacts. But you defined your map as having not the `C` objects themselves as keys but rather their nested `Integer` ID field numbers as keys. We need to extract the ID field value from all your contacts (your `C` objects, here, our `Person` objects).

So we establish a set of all the persons’ ID field value, a `Set< Integer >`. Generally best to default to immutability, so I return an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) as provided by [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet`.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableSet())

```
Set < Integer > idsOfPeople = people.stream().map( person -> person.id() ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() );
```

Same line of code, adding commentary.

```java
Set < Integer > idsOfPeople =
        people
                .stream()                                 // Make a stream of our `List` of `Person` objects.
                .map( person -> person.id() )             // For each `Person` object in our stream, produce the ID field value to produce a new stream of `Integer` objects.
                .collect(                                 // Gather the `Integer` objects from our second stream into a collection.
                        Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()    // Produce an unmodifiable set into which we collect our `Integer` objects.
                );                                        // Return a `Set< Integer >`, a set of integer objects.
```

By the way… At first I thought to add a [`.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) call after the `map` call, in case we had duplicate `Person` objects in the list. But calling `.distinct()` is superfluous because a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) by definition eliminates duplicates.

Now on to removing entries from our map where the key of the entry is found to match a Person ID in our set `idsOfPeople`. The trick is that the `Set` interface has no method for `removeAllEntriesWhereKeyIsFoundInSet`. But there is an indirect route to accomplish that goal.

The [`Map#keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) method produces as special kind of set, a set that is a *view* onto the keys in the map, not a separate independent set. If we delete a key from that key-set, we also delete its entry from the map.

Bonus: The `Set` interface includes a [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method. If we call `removeAll`, while passing our `idsOfPeople` set, on our special key-set view, we effectively remove all the entries where entry key is found in `idsOfPeople`.

For more discussion, see [*Remove multiple keys from Map in efficient way?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17675804/642706).

```
mapOfPersonIdToAnswer.keySet().removeAll( idsOfPeople );
```

Result when run. As expected, we are left with only a single entry in our map, the last entry, the one for ID 4 for which we have no such person in our `people` list.

> mapOfPersonIdToAnswer = {4=Akita}

Not that I recommend it, but you could turn those two lines into a single-line.

```
mapOfPersonIdToAnswer.keySet().removeAll( people.stream().map( person -> person.id() ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() ) );
```

As I said above, this is not better than the Wasserman solution, but it was fun to explore.

Here is the entire code example.

```java
package work.basil.mapping;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo () {
        record Person( Integer id , String name ) { }
        List < Person > people = List.of(
                new Person( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
                new Person( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
                new Person( 3 , "Carol" )
        );


        Map < Integer, String > mapOfPersonIdToAnswer =
                new HashMap <>(
                        Map.of(
                                1 , "Poodle" ,
                                3 , "Cockatiel" ,
                                4 , "Akita"
                        ) );

        Set < Integer > idsOfPeople = people.stream().map( person -> person.id() ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() );
        mapOfPersonIdToAnswer.keySet().removeAll( idsOfPeople );

        System.out.println( "mapOfPersonIdToAnswer = " + mapOfPersonIdToAnswer );

    }
}
```